Main character reincarnated in a story he wrote as punishment for his ending
The story starts with the main character dead (I forgot how and why he died or maybe it doesn't get explained in the story) and he meet Yama, the death god that read the main character's story and got mad about something in the story's plot. Yama punishes him to reincarnate in the world of the story. He possesses a system like the main character in the story, but it's the opposite of his. I remember the manga having the title "Son in Law", but I can't find anything like that or maybe I just misremember it with another story.

You tagged this with cultivation and martial-arts. Can you [edit] details on those into the question? And did you get a chance to check out Forced to Become the VIllain's Son-in-Law?

Oh, thanks dude. I forgot I was asking this question because no one has answered it. Sorry for waiting

Likely Forced to Become the Villain's Son-in-law

A third-rate writer that is destined to go to hell because of it's novel bad ending, got reincarnated in his own novel instead, reborn as the villainous son-in-law - Li Yu Guo. The battle of wits and courage between him and the original protagonist begins now.

It appears it was "Lan Luo Wang, King of Hell" that he was brought to judgment against. He was reincarnated as the villain of the piece, who apparently was easily defeated early in the story (what Lan Luo Wang hates about it was that the author apparently just abruptly destroyed the world after deciding that having an omnipotent protagonist who so easily defeated his enemy wasn't much fun). He is granted a system, of "online shopping", tenuously tied to some pepper he ordered just before his death. This is apparently the opposite of an "urban legend" about a character who could access such a system to randomly get what he needed, versus here where anything is bought consciously, but he's starting with a zero balance.




Found with a search for isekai author punished by god to live in the world he created
